# Adding event listener to another file

Tags: php, jquery

Okay this one is really tricky for me, I've got 2 files a.php(in which I include b.php) and b.php. In a.php file I echo a variable containing navigation with some divs. In b.php file I'm holding this navigation in variable $layoutNavigation. How do I add an event listener to divs inside this $layoutNavigation? I've tried these ways:

1)I've tried to do it in a regular way:

```
$(".navMenuOpener").on("click", openNavMenu);

function openNavMenu()
{
    alert();
}
```

2)Attempt(td is container in which I echo out navigation from b.php file):

```
$("#container > table td").on("click", "nav > #navigation > #web_links > .navMenuOpener", openNavMenu);

function openNavMenu()
{
    alert();
}
```

I don't want to rewrite on every .navMenuOpener element onclick attribute, since that's pretty messy, what should I try?

EDIT:
I'm pretty sure that if I add event listeners in a.php file everything would work fine, but I want to keep my layout in b.php file and all scripts that are responsible for anything that has something to do with layout.

Comment: You got any errors then?

Comment: The PHP, including the inclusion of files within files, should have no bearing on this. What is the resulting HTML output?

Comment: The html elements in $navigationLayout variable gets outputed, but I can't seem to find a way to add event listener to those elements

Comment: There's no absolute sense to do like `nav > #navigation > #web_links` you can go directly for `#web_links` (remember that ID is unique?)

Comment: It would be much more helpful to show your HTML source output and your javascript source output to illustrate your problem.  As commented on earlier, the PHP really has nothing to do with this other than being the means by which the HTML/javascript source is output. It is impossible to know how to fix the jQuery selector without seeing your HTML source.

Comment: Where is this being called at? In the head? You probably need to wait for the page to render $(document). ready()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to call a method:

```
$(".navMenuOpener").on("click", openNavMenu()); //you are missing the parentheses
```

Also, if this is in the head or even in the body you most likely want to wait for the page to render

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navMenuOpener").on("click", openNavMenu());
    //Other code
});
```

Comment: Strange, I was pretty sure that I tried this way out, tried it one more time and... it worked...